# Rapidjson. Чего хочет SetString и как ему угодить?

Tags: c++, json, строки

Использую Rapidjson.
Возникла нужда изменять строку.

```
string temp;
temp = doc["inventory"]["cells"][i]["title"].GetString();
```

Вполне себе работает.

```
doc["inventory"]["cells"][i]["title"].SetString("empty");
```

Тоже работает;

```
doc["inventory"]["cells"][i]["title"].SetString(temp);
```

не работает. Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция.

```
temp.c_str()
```

Тоже не жуёт. указание длины тоже не помогает.
Не помогает также запихать ему из того же документа `GetString()` какой-нибудь.
Также не помогло указание длины строки (есть такая перегрузка).
А очень надо.

Comment: Можно полное сообщение об ошибке дословно?

Comment: Ошибка (активно) E0304 отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::SetString [с Encoding=rapidjson::UTF8<char>, Allocator=rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]", соответствующие списку аргументов SFML C:\Users\lexpartizan\source\repos\SFML\SFML\main.cpp 1050

Answer (score 0):

```
string temp;
const char * str = &temp[0];
doc["inventory"]["cells"][i]["title"].SetString(str, doc.GetAllocator());
```

Вроде нашёл решение. Нужно вызвать аллокатор, чтобы документ перестроился в памяти.
Запихнуть голую строку ему всё же не удалось, только `const char *str;`

Comment: Если работает это, значит будет работать и `temp.c_str()`.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, c_str() тоже заработал.

Answer (score -2):

```
const char *s = &temp[0];
doc["inventory"]["cells"][i]["title"].SetString(s,temp.size());
```

Вот так прожевало.
Фух.

Рано радовался. В самом документе это не сохраняется.
Как только `*s` уходит из области видимости - так сразу изменения обнуляются.
Это логично, ведь я дал ему ссылку на переменную s, а она исчезла. То есть, он не копирует, а просто подставляет ссылку.

Вопрос остаётся. Каким образом можно изменить строку, чтобы это сохранилось в документе `rapidjson`? С интами, по крайней мере, никаких проблем нет.